# Laravel Model relations

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot connect to model function in **laravel 5.6**

```
     <img src="{{$item->file_id ? $item->photo->file_url() : 
    "http://www.ecmsnews.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png"}}"  
     width="200" height="100">
```

here I call **$item file_id** to find the image

```
public function photo(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CRM_STAFF\Staff_files', 'file_id');
  }
```

that I have in model to connect to other model to use this function

```
 public function file_url(){
        return ($this->_domain).($this->id);
}
```

but i get error like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Xo4.png)

Comment: is file_url() declared in te Photo model ? if not where is it declared ?

Comment: Hook up a debugger, find the $item returning the error, verify that the file id exists in the table that represents Staff_files.  You probably need better referential integrity checks on your FK.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to check if the relationship exists rather than if a file_id exists? ie `$item->photo ? $item->photo->file_url() : "http://www.ecmsnews.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png"`

Comment: @SteveNosse $item->photo->file_url() is $item->model->model

Comment: @Devon $item->file_id has [932]

Comment: @AhmadUsmanov, I didn't say there wasn't a file id.  I said verify the file id exists in the related table.  \

Comment: @MattJameson sorry but how to check it? If not what should I do?

Comment: @Devon its exactly exists

Comment: @MattJameson I get same error as on photo below the issue

Comment: @AhmadUsmanov then you don't have your relationship set up correctly.  Do the keys match?

Comment: @Devon that is problem, keys match 100% but no connection

Comment: try specifying both keys in the belongs to relationship rather than just the foreign key

Comment: Can you add both foreign_key and local_key when defining the relation and test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `with('photo')` in the model to load the relation. then check if `$item->photo` is not null

```
$item = Item::with('photo')->where(...)->get();
return view('yourview', compact('item'));
```

then in the view

```
<img src="{{!is_null($item->photo) ? $item->photo->file_url() : "http://www.ecmsnews.com/wp-content/themes/nucleare-pro/images/no-image-box.png"}}" width="200" height="100">
```

Comment: Eager loading is optional and using it in combination with first() is pretty unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for advise sir, 
But I think you misunderstand the problem
I do check on null but the field is not null and I think I cannot connect 2 models with each other

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who wanted to help
I found answer 
the problem was that I was saving all files with Json_encode I had to just decode it